# Get More Reduce Tasks in rdd.TreeAggregate

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

Another Spark question for you!

So im training an a SVM model using mllibs native SVMWithSGD. The training rdd is divided into 114 partitions with about 2700 instances per partition.

Each iteration job is divided in two stages. The first stage, scales linearly with my nodes. The second stage however, is only divided into 10 or so tasks, much less than available V-cores, so this stage dos not scale linearly.

I want this stage to be divided into more tasks, so that more executors can work on it in parallel. Is there any way to go about doing that?

Further there is a massive Scheduler Delay which i have come to understand is the time it takes for communication between executors and scheduler.

Comment: So what i wanted wasn't more reducer tasks, but FEWER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the dimensionality of your feature vector? 114 partitions of 2700 training instances is only 300k training examples. Depending on dimensionality, you should look at repartitioning the RDD to a much lower number of partitions (say 5-10).

Comment: 11 725 480 attributes where about 3300 are non zero. In a sparse vector. So less input partitions would yield more reducer tasks?

Comment: Also, wouldn't repartitioning the rdd to a lwoer number reduce the amount of executors that can work on it?

Comment: To be honest, 300k training examples can very comfortably be handled by a non-parallel implementation (such as scikit-learn). I would not use Spark for this unless necessary for some other reason (e.g. Spark is part of the feature extraction / processing pipeline). If you do use Spark, I would expect that fewer partitions would allow more work to be done by each executor (since the network communication would dominate the overall cost). Try fewer partitions and see what the overall impact on run-time is.

Comment: So i tried reducing the RDD into 5 partitions, and vóila, the scheduler delay decreased by 66%. Thank you Nick